# How to make a vertical div container connected from top to bottom to the page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div like the one found on youtube.com on the left side (where one finds all the options like trending, subscribed, etc.) which connects from top to bottom and stays while scrolling.

My Markup -

```css
.navDiv {
  /* Need to give the navDiv its dimentions */
  /* height: 50px; */
  width: 220px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(41, 41, 41, 1);
  height: 500px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* background-color: white; */
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navDiv">
    <div class="logo">
      <img id="logoImage" src="images/logo.png">
      <!-- <a href="" target="_blank"><img id="logoImage" src="images/logo.png"></a> -->
    </div>

    <div class="navBarItems">
      <button class="profileItem">My Profile</button>
      <button class="exploreItem">Explore</button>
      <button class="uploadItem">Upload</button>

      <!-- <ul>
           <li class="profileItem">My Profile</li>
           <li class="exploreItem">Explore</li>
           <li class="uploadItem">Upload</li>
         </ul> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```css
.navDiv {
  position: fixed;
  width: 220px;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navDiv">

  <div class="logo">
    <img id="logoImage" src="images/logo.png">
  </div>

  <div class="navBarItems">
     <button class="profileItem">My Profile</button>
     <button class="exploreItem">Explore</button>
     <button class="uploadItem">Upload</button>
   </div>

</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So the vertical movement works as I hoped. However, the div does not extend from the top to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Outsider Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

```css
.navDiv {
  position: fixed;
  width:200px;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
.logo{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 5px 0px
}
.navBarItems{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}
.profileItem,.exploreItem,.uploadItem{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  margin:3px 0px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navDiv">

  <div class="logo">
    <img id="logoImage" src="images/logo.png">
  </div>

  <div class="navBarItems">
     <button class="profileItem">My Profile</button>
     <button class="exploreItem">Explore</button>
     <button class="uploadItem">Upload</button>
   </div>

</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
</div>
```